# how to copy existing database after app installed in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have DB in assets folder i want to copy it in database folder during the installation,
Is there any way to do that?

OR if there aren't way to do that is there a way to make progress bar while the app coping the  database after the app launched ?

Edit:

I have problem with database 
logcat "shows cannot open file at line 30176" 
i tried this

```
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
    } else {
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
```

but it's not working :(

Comment: it's not
my code work fine but i want to coping the database before the app launched not after

Comment: You can't run any code of your application before it is launched. Your best option would be trying to copy it from the static constructor of an `Application` class (you might not have access to a `Context` here) or the beginning of your `Application`'s `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my DataBaseHelper.java

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH="data/data/yourPackageName/databases/";
private static final String DB_NAME="yourDbName.db";
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private final Context myContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.myContext = context; 
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    SQLiteDatabase db_read = null;

    if(dbExist){
        //Do nothing

    }else{

        db_read = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db_read.close();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new Error("Error copying database (createDataBase)");
        }
    }

}

public boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();

}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db. Destination folder (where we created the DB empty)
    String outFileName = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    //Open the empty db as the output stream. //We opened it BBDD empty as OutputStream
    OutputStream myOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    Log.e("LocAndroid", "ESTOY EN copyDataBase");


    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int lenght;


    while((lenght = myInput.read(buffer))!=-1){
        if(lenght > 0){

            myOutPut.write(buffer, 0, lenght);


        }

    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutPut.flush();
    myOutPut.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{


    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}


public synchronized void close(){

    if(myDatabase != null){
        myDatabase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

LoadDbASync.java

```
public class LoadDbAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean>{

    Context context;
    boolean loadedDb = false;
    //private Activity mActivity;

    //constructor
     public LoadDbAsync(Context context) {
            //mActivity = activity;
         this.context = context;
        }

    private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog; 

    //Se ejecutará antes del código principal de nuestra tarea. 
    //Se suele utilizar para preparar la ejecución de la tarea, inicializar la interfaz, etc
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("LocAndroid", "Entra en PreExecute");

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando Base de datos...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);//erabiltzaileak atzera botoia sakatuz ez kantzelatzeko
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);//barrarewn estiloa. Espiral bat izango da

    }

    //Se ejecutará cada vez que llamemos al método publishProgress() desde el método doInBackground().
    //se usa para poder realizar cambios en la interface. En doInBackground no se pueden realizar cambios en la interface
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        Log.i("LocAndroid", "Entra en onProgressUpdate");

        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("LocAndroid", "Entra en doInBackground");

        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        boolean dbExist = myDbHelper.checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            loadedDb = true;


        }else{

            publishProgress(null);
        }



        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new Error ("No se puede crear. Boton Crear. try. doInBAckground");
        }
        myDbHelper.close();


        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("LocAndroid", "Entra en onPostExecute");

        if(!loadedDb){
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Log.i("LocAndroid", "Se termino de cargar la BD");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Base de datos cargada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Log.i("LocAndroid", "La BD ya estaba cargada");

        }
            try {
                    finalize();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

}
```

And then, in MainActivity.java in onCreate:

```
LoadDbAsync task = new LoadDbAsync(this);
task.execute();
```

Comment: what about android 4.2?

Comment: that code runs on android 4.2. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> it's not my code work fine but i want to coping the database before the app launched not after

That's not possible. None of your code runs before the app is launched for the first time.

> OR if there aren't way to do that is there a way to make progress bar while the app coping the database after the app launched ?

Have a look at [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) and [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

- Set up a `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncTask` `onPreExecute()`
- Copy the database in `doInBackground()`, possibly updating progress with `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`
- Dismiss the `ProgressDialog` in `onPostExecute()`